# Undefined method attr_accessible error for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to create a login of sorts. I created a User scaffold and have this code in my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name,  :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation

has_secure_password
end
```

I keep getting this error

```
undefined method `attr_accessible' for #<Class:0x396bc28>

Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name,  :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation

  has_secure_password
end

Rails.root: C:/Sites/web
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you on?

Comment: 1.9.3p484 is the version I'm on

Comment: Thats' Ruby..not rails.. Check like `rails -v`..

Comment: Thats your Ruby Version.What about the Rails version?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`attr_accessible` is not available for `Rails version 4+`. You would have to go with strong parameters.

With Strong Parameters, attribute whitelisting has been moved to controller level. Remove the `attr_accessible` call from your model.

Here is an example in Rails Guide of how to use **[Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)**

In your case you can do something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ## ...
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params) ## Invoke user_params method
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' 
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end       
  end
  ## ... 

  private
  ## Strong Parameters 
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

You can take a note of @Frederick comment below my answer,

> you can still use `attr_accessible` but it has been extracted into the
>   `protected_attributes` gem (although clearly strong parameters is the
>   way forwards)

Comment: How do I use has_secure_password with strong params?

Comment: Just permit the attributes `:name, :password_digest, :password, :password_confirmation` in the UsersController like shown in the example link I provided in answer.

Comment: You can still use attr_accessible but it has been extracted  into the protected_attributes gem (although clearly strong parameters is the way forwards)

Comment: @FrederickCheung +1 That's a good point, added it to my answer.